Where to store images that are added to the nuxt3 after the build?
Where to store images that are added to the application after the build? In nuxt2 I used the /static folder for this. I uploaded images there and from there I took them for the frontend. But in nuxt3 folder /public, no longer works as well. After the build everything copies to .otput/...

i used nginx and did the following setup for statically generated site:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourdomain.com;

    # Root directory for the generated static site
    root /var/www/your-nuxt-app/.output/public;

    # Serve static files directly
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # Serve the /public directory directly if you upload additional files
    location /public/ {
        alias /var/www/your-nuxt-app/public/;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }
}



if you are using SSR then we need to tweak the nginx config file a little as the app should be served with pm2 and proxy pass it to nginx.let me know if you need that.

I was thinking about nginx too, thanks for the tip, I'll give it a try now. But it's kind of weird for a nuxt. There must be a better way i think

if you are using some other service like amplify to host the static site then you need to opt for number 3. As it is the ideal choice for this kind of situation.

I use nqinx. This is solution for me now. Thank you very much!

@ViktorKushnir you are welcome, i am glad it helped you. see you around

you can do one of the following:

serve public folder directly from hosting environment and contiue uploading the images to it after the build
set up a middleware to serve images from a directory where images are uploaded after the build
external storage like s3 or any type of static file server


Thank you for fast answer! Can you explain to me pleass what it means 'serve public folder directly from hosting environment'? Best!

@ViktorKushnir i have added anothe answer as i could not paste nginx config here
